# Cannot create superuser in Postgresql via Mayan/Django

Tags: postgresql, sqlite

I already asked one question regarding a connection problem with postgresql, but there are even more. When I try:

```
MAYAN_MEDIA_ROOT=/path/to/my/mayan-media ./mayan-edms.py createsuperuser
```

it says:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3'
```

However, I do not know what else I should install or configure in any way.

```
dpkg -l | grep sqlite
ii  libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3:armel         1.5.4-3                           armel        Apache Portable Runtime Utility Library - SQLite3 Driver
ii  libsqlite0                            2.8.17-14                         armel        SQLite 2 shared library
ii  libsqlite0-dev                        2.8.17-14                         armel        SQLite 2 development files
ii  libsqlite3-0:armel                    3.16.2-5+deb9u1                   armel        SQLite 3 shared library
ii  libsqlite3-dev:armel                  3.16.2-5+deb9u1                   armel        SQLite 3 development files
ii  python-pysqlite2                      2.7.0-1                           armel        Python interface to SQLite 3
ii  python-pysqlite2-dbg                  2.7.0-1                           armel        Python interface to SQLite 3 (debug extension)
ii  sqlite                                2.8.17-14                         armel        command line interface for SQLite 2
ii  sqlite3
```

Do you have an idea, what could be missing? I am doing this in a chroot on my NAS.

Comment: SQLite or Postgres? Creating a user in each of them will be very different

Comment: Yes, I understand why you asked. I followed this guideline: https://docs.mayan-edms.com/chapters/deploying.html. In steps 1 and 8 you can see that it actually deals with postgresql. Nevertheless I get the sqlite error in step 9. Should I provide more of the traceback?